# point inclusion in a half-plane 3D

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, 3d, computational-geometry, solid-geometry

I have a 3D half-plane defined using a line segment an a point (as shown in picture taken from [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HalfPlane.html)).

[image]

I am wondering how I can detect if a point belongs to the half-plane.
Is there any way to calculate the minimum distance between point and half-plane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p$ and $v$ be the points determining the initial line segment, and let $w$ be the third point, as suggested by your image. With this notation, $w-p$ and $v-p$ represent the top and bottom arrows in the image, respectively.

A **normal vector** to your plane is $$n = (v-p)\times(w-p),$$ (where $\times$ stands for the vector cross product), and the correct half of the plane is determined by the **perpendicular direction to your segment** $(v-p)$ projected by $(w-p)$. The latter can be computed in terms of $\widehat{ v-p } := \frac{v-p}{\| v-p\|}$, that is, $$d = (w-p) - \langle w-p, \widehat{v-p} \rangle \widehat{v-p},$$
where $\langle \cdot\,, \cdot \rangle$ stands for the scalar (dot) product.

In terms of these you can check the two conditions that $x$ needs to satisfy in order to belong to your half plane:

- **Belong to the plane**, that is, $$\langle x - p, n \rangle = 0.$$
- **Form at most a right angle with $d$**, that is, $$\langle x - p, d \rangle \ge 0.$$

---

Note (after the OP's edit).

I would expect calculating the minimum distance from a point to the half plane to be computationally more expensive than verifying its membership, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: thanks for you answer, is $\widehat{v-P}$ calculating the norm vector?

Comment: $\widehat{v-p}$ is the *unit* vector obtained by dividing $(v-p)$ by its norm $\|v-p\|$.

Comment: @H'H Do you additionally need to calculate the minimum distance?

Comment: No, that was just a proposition, I do not need that